# Convert values of rows into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column in a table which can have 3 values - High, Medium , Low.

I want to display these on a web page with 3 checkboxes (High, Medium, Low) for each record in table, with the corresponding checkbox ticked based on the priority.

```
ID  Priority
-----------
1   High
2   Low
3   High
4   Medium
```

I would like to write a SQL query that returns the following output

```
ID  High  Medium  Low
---------------------
1    Y
2                  Y
3    Y
4           Y
```

The approach I thought about is:

```
select 
    ID, 
    case 
       when priority = "High" then "Y" 
       else "N" 
    end as High,
    case 
       when priority = "Medium" then "Y" 
       else "N" 
    end as Medium,
    case 
       when priority = "Low" then "Y" 
       else "N" 
    end as Low;
```

This is a toy problem of what I am actually trying to achieve.

In my real project, I have 5-6 of such options which are different for each column and there are 4 such columns using this approach is making my query very long.

Here is a example of some columns and various values they might have

- Business growth - Growing , Stable , Decline , NA
- Frequency of Checks - Often , Sometimes , Never , NA

Please advice on a simpler more efficient solution.

Comment: I tried to do it using case statement but I realised that it depends on the number of options I have and querry is getting very long.

Comment: What have you tried? Try look into using a `case` statement here

Comment: @ashish2199 That's correct, and it looks like you only have 3 options? so it's just a `case when priority = 'high' then priority else null end` `case when medium then... case when low then...`

Comment: Post the code you have tried, even if it errors or doesn't bring you the desired results.

Comment: @ashish2199 Update your post, don't put it as a comment.

Comment: Can you show a data sample closer to what you are trying to accomplish with your project? Such as it reflecting your 5-6 option with the 4 columns requirements?

Comment: @Simon Please see the modified question.

Comment: Have you tried using a Pivot - see example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15931734/1043031) or a Dynamic Pivot - see example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27532568/1043031)?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT id, 
       CASE WHEN priority = 'High' THEN 'Y' ELSE '' END AS High,
       CASE WHEN priority = 'Medium' THEN 'Y'  ELSE '' END AS Medium,
       CASE WHEN priority = 'Low' THEN 'Y'  ELSE '' END AS Low
FROM table
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @T TABLE ( ID INT, Priority NVARCHAR(50) );

INSERT INTO @T ( ID,Priority) VALUES
(1,   N'High'),
(2,   N'Low'),
(3,   N'High'),
(4,   N'Medium');

SELECT ID, ISNULL(High, F) As High, ISNULL(Medium, F) As Medium, ISNULL(Low, F) As Low
FROM
    (
        SELECT  ID, Priority, 'Y' T , '' F
        FROM @T
     ) P1
     PIVOT
     ( 
         MAX(T) for Priority IN ([High], [Medium], [Low])
      )
      P2 ORDER BY ID;
```

Result:

```
+----+------+--------+-----+
| ID | High | Medium | Low |
+----+------+--------+-----+
|  1 | Y    |        |     |
|  2 |      |        | Y   |
|  3 | Y    |        |     |
|  4 |      | Y      |     |
+----+------+--------+-----+
```

Or using `IIF()` as:

```
SELECT ID, 
       IIF(Priority = 'High', 'Y', '') AS High,
       IIF(Priority = 'Medium', 'Y', '') AS Medium,
       IIF(Priority = 'Low', 'Y', '') AS Low
FROM @T;
```

Comment: Is there a way to include other columns(Here you have included just 1 ie Priority) in pivot ? Say If I have another column with different set of values.

Answer (score 1):

The code you showed me works. What issues are you having?

```
select id
       ,case when priority = 'high' then 'y' else 'n' end as high
       ,case when priority = 'medium' then 'y' else 'n' end as medium
       ,case when priority = 'low' then 'y' else 'n' end as low
from mytable
```

Here is a rextester example you can play with [here](http://rextester.com/FNPY36589).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE` statement or [computed columns](http://sqlhint.com/sqlserver/how-to/using-computed-columns-persisted).

Comment: How to use computed columns for this ?